# How can I set breakpoints in the dlv project to debug the dlv itself?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I am currently developing a project about vscode debugging extension through the dlv dap adapter. How can I set breakpoints in the dlv project to debug the dlv itself?

Debugging method to communicate with vscode debugging plug-in